Leafletjs fitBounds not in center
I have five markers: one for the center (coordinates: 0,0), and four for each side with coordinates:
(1, 1) (1, -1) (-1, 1) (-1, -1)
I'm attempting to adjust the map to display all markers at the center.
Here's how I'm approaching it:
const locations = [
  {latitude: 1, longitude: 1},
  {latitude: 1, longitude: -1},
  {latitude: -1, longitude: 1},
  {latitude: -1, longitude: -1},
]

const markers = []
for (let location of locations) {
  markers.push(createMarker([location.latitude, location.longitude))
}

if (markers.length) {
  const group = new L.featureGroup(markers)
  map.fitBounds(group.getBounds(), paddings: [20, 20])
}

The map is now not centered. When I console log the following:
console.log(map.getBounds())

I get:
{
  _northEast: {
    lat: 0.34332069940055443,
    lng: 0.45867919921875006
  },
  _southWest: {
    lat: -0.34332069940055443,
    lng: -0.45593261718750006
  }
}

This is the result:

Why is it not centered?

Assuming createMarker is creating a L.marker instance. The default icon size is 25x41 pixels. Therefore the padding should be at least 41 pixels.
You also have a few typos in your code. One of the typos is that paddings should be singular: padding.
const map = L.map('map')
    .setView([46.801111, 8.226667], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    // make sure that OpenStreetMap is linked, skipped here due to line width
    attribution: '&copy; OpenStreetMap'
}).addTo(map);

function createMarker(latlng) {  // assuming a simple marker
    return L.marker(latlng).addTo(map);
}

const locations = [
    {latitude: 1, longitude: 1},
    {latitude: 1, longitude: -1},
    {latitude: -1, longitude: 1},
    {latitude: -1, longitude: -1},
]

const markers = [];

for (let location of locations) {
    markers.push(
        createMarker([location.latitude, location.longitude])
    );
}

if (markers.length) {
    const group = new L.featureGroup(markers);
    map.fitBounds(group.getBounds(), {
        // default icon size is 25x41 pixels
        // have at least 4 pixels padding at the top
        padding: [18, 45]
    });
}


While the points have the same distance from the map border when using padding: [18, 45], the marker don't appear centred. You could use paddingTopLeft and paddingBottomRight instead:
map.fitBounds(group.getBounds(), {
    // default icon size is 25x41 pixels
    // have at least 4 pixels padding at the top and bottom
    paddingTopLeft: [18, 45],
    paddingBottomRight: [18, 4]
});



PS: You can get the icon size by calling (in case you are using another marker):
console.log(markers[0].getIcon().options.iconSize);

And, maybe you want to consider adjusting the zoomSnap:
const map = L.map('map', { zoomSnap: 0.2 })
    .setView([46.801111, 8.226667], 13);

